# How to write an object in which there is an unknown number of rows in the graphQl schema

Tags: javascript, graphql

I want to make a schema in graphQl for such an object:

```
author: "name",
sessions: 12345, 
path: "link", 
title: "Post-title", 
oneWeekSession : {
                    202001: 123,
                    202002: 124,
                 }
```

that's what i have now

```
        type CustomHits {
        session: Int,
        title: String,
        path: String,
        title: String,
        oneWeekSession : {???}
    }
  `
```

How to write oneweekSessions so that it has any number of lines?

Comment: You should make `oneWeekSession` an array of objects instead. Something like `[{ date: 202001, value: 123 }]`. Or use a custom scalar like shown in the linked post.

Comment: Thank you, this is probably what I need